# How to display 2 columns per row using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to display 2 columns every row but I can't seem to get it right at the moment.

What i'm trying to replicate is this:
[image: what i'm trying to achieve]

but i'm not sure on how to handle this with using flexbox

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box green">positive 1</div>
  <div class="box yellow">positive 2</div>
  <div class="box blue">positive 3</div>
  <div class="box red">negative 1</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1a9qLx5w/

Comment: i would go for grid, but for the fun, multicolumn could do the job too https://jsfiddle.net/dfw3o7a4/ from your 4 boxes ... vertical margin is used to push the third box to the first column. 200% vertical margin , if 3 boxes , then 100%  https://jsfiddle.net/dfw3o7a4/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to achieve this layout would be with Grid CSS:

```css
.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box green">positive 1</div>
  <div class="box yellow">positive 2</div>
  <div class="box blue">positive 3</div>
  <div class="box red">negative 1</div>
</div>
```

But since you're asking for a flexbox solution, here you go:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 240px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box green">positive 1</div>
  <div class="box yellow">positive 2</div>
  <div class="box blue">positive 3</div>
  <div class="box red">negative 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the alternate solution! if I would like to reverse the order via grid how would I do that?

Comment: This answer is perfection +1

Answer (score 0):

Working demo :

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="box green">positive 1</div>
    <div class="box yellow">positive 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box blue">positive 3</div>
    <div class="box red">negative 1</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your example:

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.green{
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.red{
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.col{
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="green">Positive 1</p>
    <p class="green">Positive 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p class="red">No Thanks</p>
  </div>
</div>
```